# keyboard shortcut to show history Gnome Clipboard Indicator

Tags: gnome-shell

Moving from Windows 10 to Linux. I installed the Gnome shell extension Clipboard Indicator. I would like to open the clipboard history with a keyboard shortcut and then use arrow keys and enter to select an item to paste. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4):

I came here through searching on how to change this, as this seems to be quite common.

You have to click exactly on the Label <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F*nn*</kbd> in the Settings to get be able to change the shortcut.

A related issue can be found on the project's [GitHub page](https://github.com/Tudmotu/gnome-shell-extension-clipboard-indicator/issues/205).

[image: image of settings menu]

Answer (score 1):

Found it. It is documented at the bottom of the settings screen. Ctrl+F9